# Assign Terraform output to a variable within Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, ansible, terraform, jenkins-pipeline

I am creating an EC2 instance using aws_cloudformation_stack and capturing it's output for private_ip. I want to use this output within my jenkins pipeline so that I can assign it to a variable and then inject that variable into my ansible vars file.

I am having a lot of trouble assigned the value of the terraform output to my private_ip variable in jenkins.

Is something like this possible in terraform or should I be working with a template file instead?

TF code :

```html
resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "test_instance" {
  ...
}

output "test_instance_private_ip" {
  value = aws_cloudformation_stack.test_instance.outputs.PrivateIp
}
```

Jenkins pipeline code :

```html
def private_ip
stage('terraform'){
  sh """
    terraform init
    terraform plan
    terraform apply --auto-approve
  """
  private_ip = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "terraform output test_instance_private_ip").trim()
}

stage('ansible') {
  sh """
    ansible-playbook -i inventory.yml --limit testgroup -e "private_ip=${private_ip}" playbook.yml -v
  """
}
```

Current output :

```
Warning: No outputs found
Warning: Empty or non-existent state
```

Comment: That would imply the `apply` was not successful. In general, it would be easiest to generate Ansible inventory from Terraform with the `local` provider (this is the most common design pattern). This file would persist in your Jenkins Workspace between the stages also, whereas the variable may end up being out of scope and resolve to `nil` in the successive stages.

Comment: @MattSchuchard thank you for your response. I was doing `terraform output` right after the `apply` and it was outputting the values correctly. However, writing the output to a `json` file and then retrieving it via `jq` worked for me.

Comment: @br0wnm4n any updates? I have the same issue